# FileOutputStream(No such file or directory)(No such file or directory)

Tags: java, file-io, tar, fileoutputstream, apache-commons-compress

I am extracting a TarGz file and am getting a (No such file or directory) with the following line:

```
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + entry.getName());
```

My code:

```
private static void extractTarGz(String filePath, String outputPath) throws IOException {
    try{
        TarArchiveInputStream tais = new TarArchiveInputStream(new GzipCompressorInputStream( new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(filePath))));
        TarArchiveEntry entry;
        
        while ((entry = (TarArchiveEntry) tais.getNextEntry()) != null) {
          //Create directories as required
          if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            File f = new File(outputPath + entry.getName());
            f.mkdirs();
          }else {
            int count;
            int size = (int)entry.getSize();
            byte data[] = new byte[size];
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + entry.getName());
            BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,size);
            while ((count = tais.read(data, 0, size)) != -1) {
              dest.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            dest.close();
        
          }
        
        }
      } catch(Exception e) {
          log.error(e);
      }
}
```

It gets to `parentdir/childdir/file` and then gives the error.
I even tried the following to create the file, but still no luck

```
if (!f.exists()) {
    f.createNewFile();
}
```

Any help understand what I am missing?

Answer (score -1):

Does

> entry.getName()

contain the file type in the name? eg. .jpg? .gif? etc.
Also f is missing a ;

Comment: Apologies for that typo, I will correct that. Yes entry.getName() does get the file extention too, eg `stack1.PNG`. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).